# Random_shuffle can run without <algorithm> library?

Tags: c++, random, vector, c++11

I write this without including  and it runs successfully. 
Is the `srand` and the `random_shuffle` in the std library ? 
Weird isn't it?

Links [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle)  and [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/random_shuffle/) say they are in the algorithm library.

```
#include <array>
#include <time.h>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
    int main()                                          
    {
        vector<int> myvector;
        srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
        for (int i=0; i<10; ++i) 
            {myvector.push_back(i);}
        random_shuffle ( myvector.begin(), myvector.end() );
    }
```

Comment: My guess is that one of the other files includes it (for your implementation at least; mine doesn't compile either call). Try compiling a call without including any headers at all.

Comment: Something specific to your environment. Doesn't compile here for example: http://ideone.com/9meUW

Comment: Traditionally, `srand()`is in `stdlib.h` (or `cstdlib`for C++) as is shown [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/srand/). What compiler do you use?

Comment: Compiler Used is VS 2010

Comment: @georgemano VS 2010 includes `<cstdlib>` through the follwing hierarchy: **`<array>`** <= `<algorithm>` <= `<memory>` <= `<xmemory>` <= **`<cstdlib>`** . There you go. Try to **not** include `<array>` or `<vector>` (hierarchy is  **`<vector>`** <= `<memory>` <= `<xmemory>` <= **`<cstdlib>`**).

Answer (score 10):

C++ doesn't specify which standard headers are included in other standard headers, so it varies between implementations. To be portable you need to make sure that you always directly include the headers you're using, but code will often compile without that. This isn't out of the ordinary at all.

Comment: True answer in general, but I can't see how it explains this particular example. I can't fathom how any of the shown include files would include `<algorithm>`.

Comment: @MarkRansom VS11 `<array>` includes `<algorithm>`

Answer (score 1):

Many compilers have the ability to specify additional include files on the command line or in the settings. Make sure you're not automatically including those headers. Check makefiles too.

C++ won't compile the program if it doesn't have a prototype for the function you're calling.